# Signing Android APK using Jenkins

Tags: android, maven, jenkins

I have been searching around but could not see how i can have jenkins sign my apk after the build step. I am using Appaloosa integrated into Jenkins to distribute my application, but i need to have it sign before. I see there are no post build sign android targets in Android. How can i do this?

1. Add a jar sign dependency to my pom.xml
2. Use Jenkins to sign my apk before shipping.

Could anyone help me out here ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you configure your build scripts to sign (or just create build scripts for your app), you can simply run that script with Jenkins and it will sign it. This is the simplest way.

These 2 links will help you generate build.xml file for your app: http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html and http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html.